# In Corda flow, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to initiateFlow() twice in the same InitiatingFlow

Tags: corda

I have the following Corda flow, where I pass in a list of `Party`s and attempt to initiate a flow session with each one:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class MyFlow(val parties: List<Party>) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // Flow logic.

        val flowSessions = parties.forEach { party ->
            initiateFlow(party)
        }

        // Flow logic.
    }
}
```

However, when I call it, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to initiateFlow() twice in
>   the same InitiatingFlow com.template.TwoTransactionsFlow@1ba8d137 for
>   the same party O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB. This isn't supported in this
>   version of Corda. Alternatively you may initiate a new flow by calling
>   initiateFlow() in an @InitiatingFlow sub-flow.

What is the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 1):

This exception indicates that you have attempted to initiate a flow session twice with the same party within the same flow context, in this case because the `parties` list you're passing into the flow contains duplicates. This is not allowed.

You should either:

1. Re-use existing sessions with a given party (i.e. create a single `FlowSession` with `PartyA` and use the same flow session to send `PartyA` information twice)
2. Subflow into another `@InitiatingFlow` and create the `FlowSession` there (each `@InitiatingFlow` and its in-lined subflows share the same flow context)